# while doing ng build --prod, jw-angular-pagination throwing error

Tags: angular, pagination

I am using `"jw-angular-pagination": "^1.1.0"`

> ERROR in
>   node_modules/jw-angular-pagination/lib/jw-pagination.component.d.ts.JwPaginationComponent.html(8,9):
>   : Property 'setPage' is private and only accessible within class
>   'JwPaginationComponent'.

Comment: This issue is still open https://github.com/cornflourblue/jw-angular-pagination/issues/8, you can build without aot compilation `ng build --prod --aot=false`

Answer (score 4):

I see a lot of people experiencing this but I found a way around it. If you are deploying to heroku like me, removing 'private' from setPage alone won't work as heroku will have to run `npm install` and `ng build --prod` all the time and this downloads fresh copy with same bug.

A PR has been made the repository [here](https://github.com/cornflourblue/jw-angular-pagination/pull/10) though but it hasn't been merged. While we hope it gets merged soon. Here's what I did:

- I extracted the packages by moving them(jw-angular-pagination and jw-paginate) away from node_modules to a separate folder called 'packages'(name it anything you want). Mine is located at src/app/packages
- In packages/jw-angular-pagination/lib/jw-angular-pagination.js on line 3, change jw-paginate line to `var paginate = require("../../jw-paginate/lib/jw-paginate");`
- Go to your app.module.ts and change the import to: `import { JwPaginationComponent } from "./packages/jw-angular-pagination/lib/jw-pagination.component";`

Don't forget to run `npm uninstall jw-angular-pagination` so it doesn't conflict. And delete it from package.json

Answer (score 1):

The problem is about you are building your project with AOT mode.
AOT is by default true for production builds, just turn it off.

```
ng build prod --aot=false
```

Comment: This gives further error as "An unhandled exception occurred: The 'buildOptimizer' option cannot be used without 'aot'"

Answer (score 0):

run `npm uninstall jw-angular-pagination`

change `"jw-angular-pagination": "^1.1.0"` to `"jw-angular-pagination": "1.1.0"`

run `npm install`

Answer (score -1):

It's working for me after deleting `private` notation in `setPage` method in:

`node_modules/jw-angular-pagination/lib/jw-pagination.component.d.ts`